# Formatting - \citetitle - dutch quotation style

Tags: biblatex, csquotes

In Dutch, we quote ``like this''

I `usepackage{biblatex}` which does autoquoting. When I `\citetitle`, I get  „Title” but I need ``*Title*''

Who can help me hack `\citetitle` so the title becomes *italic* and correctly ``quoted'' and/or give me the correct `\setquotestyle{xxx}` for `csquotes`?

thank you!

Comment: The quotations you are seeing are the quote styles contributed to `csquotes`. If these styles are incorrect and you have a source to back you up, please let the author know what the correct style is: https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/issues. Aha https://onzetaal.nl/taaladvies/aanhalingstekens-hoog-of-laag: seems there are no rules, but  „Title” is OK.

Answer (score 1):

https://onzetaal.nl/taaladvies/aanhalingstekens-hoog-of-laag seems to suggest that the lower-upper quotation marks are still in use in some publications, on the other hand the upper (66)-upper (99) form seems to have become more widespread recently.

You can switch the default style of Dutch quotation marks with `\DeclareQuoteStyle`

```
\documentclass[dutch]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareQuoteStyle{dutch}
  {\textquotedblleft}
  {\textquotedblright}
  [0.05em]
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Goedendag \enquote{hoi}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally https://www.taaltelefoon.be/aanhalingstekens-%E2%80%98-%E2%80%99-%E2%80%9C-%E2%80%9D-%E2%80%9E-%E2%80%9D also lists and actually uses the combination like upper(9)-upper(9).

Comment: NOS.nl uses straight double quotes, NRC.nl lower(99)-upper(99), Volkskrant.nl straight single upper quotes, trouw.nl upper(6)-upper(9), nu.nl uses stright double quotes, telegraaf.nl lower(99)-upper(99), standaard.be upper(6)-upper(9), rijksoverheid.nl (at least on the page I checked) upper(6)-upper(9)